# Solved: Grep and Dynamically Truncate at Same Time

Tags: bash

**Given the following**:

```
for(condition which changes $z)
    aptitude show $z | grep -E 'Uncompressed Size: |x' | sed s/Uncompressed Size: //";
done
```

That means 3 items are outputting to screen (`$Z`, `Uncompressed Size`, `x`).
I want all of that to fit on one line, and a line I deem is = 100 characters.
So, (`$Z`, `Uncompressed Size`, `x`) must fit on one line.  But `X` is very long and will have to be truncated.  So there is a requirement to add "used" characters by `$z` and Uncompressed Size, so that `x` can be truncated dynamically.  I love scripting and being able to do this I deem an absolute must.  Needless to say all 3 items being output to screen change hence the characters of the first two outputs must be calculated to subtract from the allowed characters for x, and sum of all characters between all 3 items cannot exceed 100 characters.

sed 's/.//5g'

Lmao, sometimes I wish I thought in simpler terms; complicated description + simple solution = simple problem over complicated by interpreter.

Thank you, Barmar

That only leaves sed (100 - amount of characters used by $z which is this function: ${#z}

Comment: Put the output into a variable, then echo the first 100 characters.

Comment: Why is `Uncompressed Size` outputting to the screen? You're removing it with `sed`.

Comment: to make more room for x, remember you are grepping uncompressed size which besides that label has a unique size.  Name and unique size and x is sufficient.  While looking for how to echo x number of characters I found an answer: grep .... | cut -c 1-N   or sed 's/.//5g' <<< "defn-test"...output
defn